# get the first input type hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this table

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <input type='hidden' value='{{$user->username}}' />
                    <td><div contenteditable="true" class='contenteditable'>{{$user->username}}</div><div class='result'></div></td>
                    <td><div contenteditable="true" class='contenteditable'>{{$user->email}}</div><div class='result'></div></td>
                    <td>
                        <select class='form-control'>
                        @foreach($permissions as $permission)
                            @if($permission->id == $user->permission)
                                <option style='color:red' selected='true'>{{$permission->permission_name}}</option>
                            @else
                                <option>{{$permission->permission_name}}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><div contenteditable="true" class='contenteditable'>{{$user->phone}}</div><div class='result'></div></td>
                    <td>
                        <select class='form-control'>
                        @foreach($divisions as $division)
                            @if($division->id == $user->division)
                                <option style='color:red' selected='true'>{{$division->division_name}}</option>
                            @else
                                <option>{{$division->division_name}}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <div class='result'></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class='btn btn-success'>عرض</button>
                        <button class='btn btn-info'>تعديل</button>
                        <button class='btn btn-danger'>حذف</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

and i have this js function to get the input type hidden value like this

```
$(".contenteditable").keyup(function(){
   var result = document.activeElement;
   var result = result.parentNode.firstChild;
   console.log(result);
 })
```

what i need is javascript or jquery code when i keyup the contenteditable div i get the first value

```
<input type='hidden' value='{{$user->username}}' />
```

Comment: $('input[type=hidden]:first').val()

Comment: i have many of input type=hidden

Comment: then use it first jquery selector or use id to the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should traverse upto `tr` element using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) along with `:first` selector to target `:hidden` element

```
$(".contenteditable").keyup(function(){
   var result = $(this).closest('tr').find('[type="hidden"]:first').val();
   console.log(result);
});
```

Note: `tr` can only have `td` or `th` as child elements. So `<input>` should be child of either of them